# C++, volatile и блокируемые разделяемые объекты

Tags: c++, volatile

У меня есть несколько вопросов про `volatile` в `C++`:

1. Существует мнение, что разделяемые объекты (аля, связный список, все методы которого защищены внутренним мьютексом) не нужно делать `volatile` при использовании из разных потоков. Вопрос - почему? Если `volatile` нужен для объяснения компилятору того факта, что значение может измениться неожиданным образом и его не нужно оптимизировать, тогда почему связный список, который синхронизирует доступ к себе сам, нормально работает при использовании из разных потоков и без спецификатора `volatile`?
2. Какова семантика метода, который помечен спецификатором `volatile`?
3. Когда вообще нужно применять спецификатор `volatile`? Пример с циклом, который управляется флагом, который меняется из другого потока, слишком упрощен и при рассмотрении реальных сценариев `C++` ясности не дает никакой.

Comment: `volatile` не предназначен для синхронизации объектов. Смысл этого ключевого слова в том, чтобы препятствовать оптимизациям компилятора. Когда компилятор видит `volatile`-объект, он предполагает, что этот объект может быть модифицирован способом, который компилятор не в состоянии проконтролировать. Но это не означает, что `volatile`-объект можно безопасно читать/модифицировать из разных потоков. "Пример с циклом, который управляется флагом, который меняется из другого потока" - если единственный способ синхронизации обращений к флагу - `volatile`-квалификатор - то это UB.

Comment: [dcl.type.cv/6](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type.cv#6): "`volatile` is a hint to the implementation to avoid aggressive optimization involving the object because the value of the object might be changed by means undetectable by an implementation."

Comment: А каким образом разделяемый объект, который защищен собственным мьютексом, не будучи `volatile`, начинает избегать оптимизации?

Comment: [Volatile and multithreading: is the following thread-safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6592287)

Comment: Я понимаю, что `volatile` это не про атомарность и не про синхронизацию, я спрашиваю немного о другом.

Comment: Ссылка в моём  предыдущем комментарии - это дополнение к моим более ранним комментариям относительно `volatile`, а не ответ на ваш вопрос в комментарии. Просто я не успел добавить ссылку прежде, чем вы задали доп. вопрос.

Comment: Надо было делать 4 - 5 разных вопросов...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Существует мнение, что разделяемые объекты (аля, связный список, все методы которого защищены внутренним мьютексом) не нужно делать volatile при использовании из разных потоков. Вопрос - почему?

Потому что сам примитив синхронизации (мютекс) является "барьером". Тема обширная и в одном ответе не раскрыть. Но можно начать читать здесь http://scrutator.me/post/2012/04/04/parallel-world-p1.aspx и Энтони Уильям - Книга "Параллельное программирование на C++ в действии. Практика разработки многопоточных программ"

Но если говорить простым языком, то если один потом модифицировал разные переменные и отпустил мютекс, а другой захватил этот же мютекс и пытается читать эти же переменные, то их состояние будет "ожидаемым". А без захвата мютекса - не факт.

> Какова семантика метода, который помечен спецификатором volatile?

ну нет в с++ методов. Есть функция член класса, ну или просто функция. А семантика такая же как и const - Ваш this будет volatile.

> Когда вообще нужно применять спецификатор volatile? Пример с циклом, который управляется флагом, который меняется из другого потока, слишком упрощен и при рассмотрении реальных сценариев C++ ясности не дает никакой.

volatile следует применять при разработке драйверов и микроконтроллеров. Основаная суть volatile раскрывает такой пример

```
volatile int a;
a = 1;
a = 2;
```

без volatile компилятор просто выбросит первое присваивание. Оно бессмысленно. А с volatile запись будет произведена дважды. Зачем? а переменная a может быть связанна с каким то внешним устройством и запись в эту переменную будет делать запись в какой то порт ввода-вывода. И оптимизация будет только мешать.

Comment: Спасибо за объяснения.